# Return None if list is empty

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def get_min(int_list):
    if len(int_list) == 0:
        return None
```

Basically, if an empty list is passed, it should return "None" in the terminal:

```
python3 -i PA03.py
get_min([])
```

As I said, it should return "None" in the console but it's printing nothing. I'm not allowed to use print().

Comment: return “None“ ?

Comment: If an expression in the console evaluates to `None`, nothing is printed. This is normal.

Comment: Yeah then it returns `'None'` as a String but I want it to return `None`.

Comment: No @MichaelButscher, I had programs where `return None` printed `None` in the terminal. However, it's not working with that code above ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must `return "None"` and you can use this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(get_min([]))
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any frameworks :/

Comment: Are you not allowed to use any function or simplky any library that can do it? Because using `print` you're uising a built-in function. Using `sys` you're using a library